# Plot a parametric function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, piecewise

I want to plot the following function defined on $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]\setminus(0,0)$:

$$
F(x,y,t)=
\begin{cases} 
(1-t)(x,y)+t(1,\frac{y}{x})& \text{if}\ -x\leq y\leq x  \\
(1-t)(x,y)+t(\frac{x}{y},1)& \text{if}\ -y\leq x \leq y \\
(1-t)(x,y)+t(-1,-\frac{y}{x})& \text{if}\quad\  x\leq y \leq -x \\
(1-t)(x,y)+t(-\frac{x}{y},-1)& \text{if}\quad\  y \leq x \leq -y \\
\end{cases}
$$

What would be great is if I could write a code which takes two values $a$ and $b$ and then plots something like a moving graph, of where $(a,b)$ goes as $t$ changes.

Comment: Can you post the function in Mathematica code? Look up `Piecewise` if needed.

Comment: Start small: Look up `Piecewise` first and see if you can get that working for a particular choice of `t`. Then see if you can make the same function with `t` as a parameter and see if you can plot the individual ones at different `t`'s. Then, once all that's working, look up `Manipulate` and see if you can get the "animation" working. Finally: I'm a little confused on how you want to plot a function from R2 to R2. Do you want to make a vector field or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
w[x_, y_, 
  t_] := (1 - t) {x, 
    y} + (t Sign[ x] Boole[Abs[y] <= Abs[x] ] {1, y/x} + 
    t Sign[ y] Boole[Abs[y] > Abs[x]] {x/y, 1})
Manipulate[
 Row[{Graphics[Point[pts], PlotRange -> Table[{-1, 1}, {2}], 
    Axes -> True, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200], 
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[w[##, t]], Black, 
       Point[{w[##, 0], w[##, 1]}], Line[{w[##, 0], w[##, 1]}]} & @@ 
     pts, PlotRange -> Table[{-1, 1}, {2}], Axes -> True, 
    Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200]}],
 {{pts, {-0.2, -0.2}}, Locator}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your function:

```
 f[x_, y_, t_] := Piecewise[{
   {(1 - t) {x, y} + t {1, y/x}, -x <= y <= x},
   {(1 - t) {x, y} + t {x/y, 1}, -y <= x <= y},
   {(1 - t) {x, y} + t {-1, -(y/x)}, x <= y <= -x},
   {(1 - t) {x, y} + t {-(x/y), -1}, y <= x <= -y}
  }]
```

My interpretation of what you want:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[f[a, b, t0], {t0, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
  , Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[f[a, b, t]]}]
 ]
 , {t, 0, 1}
 , {a, -2, 2}
 , {b, -2, 2}
]
```

[image]

Another possibility:

```
Manipulate[VectorPlot[f[x, y, t], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]