# Plot a piecewise function of two variables

Tags: plotting, function-construction, piecewise

How can I plot with Mathematica, Muller's example:

> $f(t,x) = \begin{cases} 0 & t \leq 0, x \in \mathbb{R}  \\ 2t & t>0,x
>  < 0  \\ 2t - \frac{4x}{t}  & t >0,0 \leq x \leq t^2  \\
>  -2t & t>0,x > t^2 \, . \end{cases}$

which is a piecewise function of two variables?

**Other examples**

[Plot a parametric function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102012/plot-a-parametric-function-from-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2?rq=1)

Comment: Have you read about `Piecewise`in the documentation?...

Comment: Try `f[x_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{0, t <= 0}, {2 t, t > 0 && x < 0}, {2 t - 4 x/t, 
    t > 0 && 0 <= x <= t^2}, {-2 t, t > 0 && x > t^2}}]` and `Plot3D`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f[t_, x_] = Piecewise[{{0, t <= 0}, {2*t, t > 0 && x < 0}, {2*t - 4*x/t, 
    t > 0 && 0 <= x <= t^2}, {-2*t, t > 0 && x > t^2}}]

Plot3D[f[t, x], {t, -4, 4}, {x, -4, 4}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: plot]